# Debugging socket.io messages in etherpad (server side)

Tags: node.js, debugging, socket.io, etherpad

I would like to get socket.io debugging information output to the console in out [etherpad](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite) instance.

Most of my investigation has revolved around using the DEBUG variable, to no avail.

What I've done :
To verify that I was using the debug variable correctly, I used the [sample chat application](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) described in the 'Getting started' section of Socket.IO

Lauching this sample chat with the DEBUG parameter set to socket.io* yields the following information :

```
DEBUG=socket.io* node index.js 
  socket.io:server initializing namespace / +0ms
  socket.io:server creating engine.io instance with opts {"path":"/socket.io"} +2ms
  socket.io:server attaching client serving req handler +2ms
listening on *:3000
```

We can see here socket.io debugging messages, as well as a message from the sample chat application (*listening on *:3000*)

Trying to start etherpad with the same DEBUG variable does not result in socket.io debug information being displayed :

```
DEBUG=socket.io* node node_modules/ep_etherpad-lite/node/server.js
  [INFO] console - Report bugs at https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/issues
  [INFO] console - Your Etherpad version is 1.5.7 (a09044a)
  [INFO] console - You can access your Etherpad instance at http://0.0.0.0:9001/
```

In both cases, I used socket.io version 1.3.5. That is the version used by [Etherpad version 1.5.7](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/releases/tag/1.5.7).

What could cause this problem ? Are the messages "caught" by etherpad and never displayed ? Should I look elsewhere ?

Comment: François Cassin : Have you got the solution of this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question, but could it be that `etherpad` doesn't use the [debug library](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug)? Their code doesn't seem to have a call to [require('debug')](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/search?p=3&q=debug+%3D+require%28%27debug%27%29&unscoped_q=debug+%3D+require%28%27debug%27%29)

Comment: alternatively, this could be related to some definitions on ehetrpad's [Settings.js](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/blob/dfd45f0f5717248bb71636d9162e3c0b4a266428/src/node/utils/Settings.js#L443); e.g.  
  `log4js.setGlobalLogLevel(exports.loglevel);
  process.env['DEBUG'] = 'socket.io:' + exports.loglevel; `